# Why is no collision detected between my enemy bullet and my player in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a space game and recently made an enemy ship that every once in a while fires bullets towards the player and if the player collides with it, it explodes and damages the player. For some reason, no collision is detected.

I tried to implement a system where my enemy would move around and fire bullets at the player based on the player's actual position at the time. I had expected a collision between bullet and player to be detected and the player would then be damaged and in huge explosion. What happened was that the collision between bullet and player was never detected. Here is my code:
Enemy code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyship : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform shootPoint;
    public float shootSpeed = 10f;
    public float timeToShoot = 2f;
    float originalTime;
    public Transform enemy;
    GameObject target;
    public float thrust = 1000f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform player;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        originalTime = timeToShoot;
        timeToShoot = 25f;
    }

    void Update() {
            enemy.LookAt(player.transform);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        timeToShoot -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeToShoot < 0)
        {
            ShootPlayer();
            timeToShoot = originalTime;
        }
        Vector3 targetLocation = player.position - transform.position;
        float distance = targetLocation.magnitude;
        rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * Mathf.Clamp((distance - 10)/50,0f,1f) * thrust);
    }
    private void ShootPlayer()
    {
        GameObject currentBullet = Instantiate(bullet,shootPoint.position, shootPoint.rotation);
        Rigidbody rig = currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        rig.AddForce(transform.forward*shootSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
```

Bullet code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int playerDamage = 10;
    public GameObject Explosion_main;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision otherobject) {
        Debug.Log("H");
        if(otherobject.collider.tag == "Player") {
            Debug.Log("R");
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            GameObject.Find("Ship").GetComponent<PlayerBehaviour>().PlayerTakeDmg(playerDamage);
            Instantiate(Explosion_main, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your rigidbody set to `Collision Detection` -> `Continuous Dynamic`? Otherwise the velocities might be too fast for the collision detection to catch them between physics frames ... `Select Continuous Dynamic if this Rigidbody is involved in fast-moving collisions with any colliders.`

Comment: And even if the collision detection is set to dynamic, really HIGH speed velocities can be missed between physics frames :(

Comment: It was set to continuous but when I set it to continuous dynamic it still didn't work

Comment: Bullet is also not detecting collision even when moving slowly

Comment: The player can  also just glide through the enemy ship but it detects collision when the player ship hits an asteroid

Comment: Solved -the mesh collider wasn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Problem

Unity calculates collisions by checking for objects overlapping in every fixed update. If your bullet is travelling really fast here is what might happen:

- Fixed update *t*

  - The bullet is moved by e. g. 2 units based on its velocity.
    Now, the bullet is right in front of the player
  - Unity checks if they are overlapping which is not the case.
- Fixed update *t+1*

  - The bullet is moved by 2 units again.
    Now, the bullet traveled through the player and is right behind them.
  - Unity checks if bullet and player are overlapping which is still not the case.

## The Easy Solution

To fix this, you can set the collision detection mode in the rigidbody component of the bullet from *discrete* to *continuous*. This tells unity to calculate whether the objects have overlapped while moving, which will fix your problem.

## The better Solution

This however isn't really ideal for performance. Especially when having a few thousand bullets travelling through the scene, this will create a lot of lag.

An alternative to continuous collision detection is handling these collisions between fixed updates yourself like this:

(in Bullet.cs)

```
private Vector3 lastPosition;
private void FixedUpdate(){
    // If the player is between the last position and the current position
    if(Physics.Linecast(transform.position, lastPosition, LayerMask.GetMask("Player"))){
        // Put your player kill logic here

    }


    // Remember the last bullet position
    lastPosition = transform.position;
}
```

As you can see, we use a layer mask here to ensure the line cast only checks the player. This means that you have to assign the players ship to a new player called `Player` in the inspector

With that code, the can check if the bullet just move through the player however I reckon you want to get all collisions that happened between fixed updated. For example collsions with asteroids so that the bullet gets destroyed when hitting one. For that, you could write your own callback that you call whenever a collision is detected either by unity or by your linecast code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int playerDamage = 10;
    public GameObject Explosion_main;
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        // In the unity collision callback, you now simply call your own collision method:
        OnCollision(collision.collider.gameObject);
    }

    // This is your OWN method, not a unity callback!
    private void OnCollsion(GameObject other){
        // Now, you handle the collision here

        if(other.tag == "Player") {
            Debug.Log("Collsion with player");
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            GameObject.Find("Ship").GetComponent<PlayerBehaviour>().PlayerTakeDmg(playerDamage);
            Instantiate(Explosion_main, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        // Example for how you could implement asteroid collisions:
        if(other.tag == "Asteroid") {
            Debug.Log("Collsion with asteroid");
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Additionally, you check for collisions between fixed updates
    private Vector3 lastPosition;
    private void FixedUpdate(){
        // To ensure that the bullet doesn't detect itself here, we create a layermask that contains every object except bullets:
        int layerMask =~ LayerMask.GetMask("Bullet");

        // If the player is between the last position and the current position
        if(Physics.Linecast(transform.position, lastPosition, out RaycastHit hitInfo, layerMask)){
            OnCollision(hitInfo.collider.gameObject);

        }

        // Remember the last bullet position
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }

}
```

Now, we need a layer exclusively for bullets to prevent the hitting themselves. So again, just give them their own layer in the inspector.

### Why the better solution is faster

When you make unity calculate collision between frames using continuous collision detection, it has to calculate them based on the colliders of the object. This isn't usually necessary for bullets because bullets are usually really thin. By using `Physics.LineCast()` we basically approximate the colllision by simplifying the collider from a e. g. really long cylinder to a single line.